# Название APK файла для Google Play.Xamarin.Forms для Android

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play

Создал APK файл проекта Xamarin.Forms на Android. На смартфоне установился успешно.
При попытке загрузить на Google Play выдается ошибка.

[image: Скриншот]

Как я понимаю дело в названии файла. но должно иметь формат  com.example.prilozhenie. Пробовал загрузить переименовав  файл в Проводнике (не в Xamarin) на com.adresssite.app1 - не получилось. Прошу помочь.

Comment: В ошибке речь не о названии apk файла, а о названии пакета вашего приложения. Копайте в сторону application id

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Копаю. Как я понимаю нужно поменять название пакета на этапе сборки в Xamarin. Только на какое? Что это за формат com.example.prilozhenie ? Может кто напишет пример? Не хочется много раз экспериментировать. Спасибо.

Comment: `com.example.prilozhenie` это и есть пример. `one.more.sample` - ещё пример. Почитайте [здесь](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html) что такое application id. Как его менять в Xamarin, я, к сожалению, не знаю

Comment: Спасибо. В Xamarin открыл манифест Android . Изменил название пакета. Название пакета у меня начиналось с большой буквы, а нужно с маленькой. Пересобрал. АРК загрузился.